# How to display text follow role?

Tags: angular, angular8

I want to display the title of the text on the edit page as the function is written.

app.html

```
<div class="header content">
      <h5 *ngIf="getRoleEditPage()">
        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
          {{ text }}
      </h5>
</div>
```

app.ts

```
  getRoleEditPage() {
    let text: string
    if (this.user.roles.customer === true) {
      text = `Customer's Edit Ticket`
    } else if (this.user.roles.supporter === true) {
      text = `Supporter's Edit Ticket`
    } else if (this.user.roles.maintenance === true) {
      text = `Maintenance's Edit Ticket`
    } else if (this.user.roles.supervisor === true) {
      text = `Supervisor's Edit Ticket`
    } else if (this.user.roles.developer === true) {
      text = `Developer's Edit Ticket`
    }
    return text
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the result from your `getRoleEditPage`, as follows (using aliasing):

```html
<div class="header content">
      <h5 *ngIf="getRoleEditPage() as text">
        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
          {{ text }}
      </h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to use a pipe here :-

```
<div class="header content">
      <h5>
        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
          {{ user | rolePipe }}
      </h5>
</div>

@Pipe({name: 'rolePipe'})
export class RolePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(user: any, args: any) {
    if (this.user.roles.customer === true) {
      return `Customer's Edit Ticket`
    } else if (this.user.roles.supporter === true) {
      return `Supporter's Edit Ticket`
    } else if (this.user.roles.maintenance === true) {
      return `Maintenance's Edit Ticket`
    } else if (this.user.roles.supervisor === true) {
      return `Supervisor's Edit Ticket`
    } else if (this.user.roles.developer === true) {
      return `Developer's Edit Ticket`
    }
    return;
  }
}
```